# Como tener en un input el diseño de precio por ejemplo $100.000.000 en django

Tags: django, input, diseño

Hola quiero saber como darle el diseño de pesos como por ejemplo este $100.000, que este como un placeholder, pero que después cuando comience a escribir dentro del input se mantenga y no se borre. Seria para implementarlo en django ya que no se como se hace

Gracias de ante mano

```py
CODIGO FORMS.PY

"""
Formulario del Credito
"""
class CreditoForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Credito
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'nroCred' : 'Numero del Credito',
            'montoCred' : 'Monto del Credito',
            'totalCuotasCred' : 'Cuotas Totales',
            'fechaPrimerPagoCred' : 'Fecha del Primer Pago',
            'cuotasPagadasCred' : 'Cuotas Pagadas Hasta el Momento',
            'instiCred' : 'Institucion Bancaria',
            'observacionCred' : 'Observaciones',
            'SoliCred' : 'Solicitud Del Credito',
            'ejecutivoCred' : 'Ejecutivo a Cargo'
        }
        widgets = {
            'nroCred' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs= {
                    'type' : 'number',
                    'class' : 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' : 'Ingrese el Numero del Credito',
                    'id' : 'nroCredito'
                }
            ),
            'montoCred' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs= {
                    'type' : 'number',
                    'class' : 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' : 'Ingrese el Monto Total',
                    'id' : 'montoCredito'
                }
            )
        }
```

En el montoCred es donde quiero darle el Diseño de $100.000 y que se mantenga por la cantidad de dinero que ingrese por ejemplo que si ingresa $100, $100.000, $100.000.000 que se vea así sucesivamente

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!